# Changing format of date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe, in which a column is a string formatted as

```
yyyymmdd
```

which should be a date. Is there an easy way to convert it to a recognizable form of date?

And then what python libraries should I use to handle them?
Let's say, for example, that I would like to consider all the events (rows) whose *date* field is a working day (so mon-fri). What is the smoothest way to handle such a task?

Comment: I was confused. You should have used dayofweek instead of day. Try it.

Comment: `dayofweek` works! Only one thing, days are numbered 0-6, so it should be `m= pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.dayofweek < 5 ` if you want to select mon-friday. Edit your answer so that I can pick it as correct, and thanks a lot :)

Comment: It is done.... :=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you want to select Mon-Friday. Do that by converting your column to datetime and check if the `dt.dayofweek` is lower than 6 (Mon-Friday --> 0-4)

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.dayofweek < 5
df2 = df[m]
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        '20180101',
        '20180102',
        '20180103',
        '20180104',
        '20180105',
        '20180106',
        '20180107'
    ],
    'value': range(7)
})

m = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.dayofweek < 5

df2 = df[m]
print(df2)
```

Returns:

```
       date  value
0  20180101      0
1  20180102      1
2  20180103      2
3  20180104      3
4  20180105      4
```

Comment: Actually. Yearfirst is more for dates like: `08/10/08`. The format is not needed.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working if I pick days beyond the 9th of each month. To reproduce it: `df= pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [
        '20180124',
        '20180123',
        '20180112',
        '20180115',
        '20180121',
        '20180102',
        '20180101'
    ]
})`

Comment: After further attempts, maybe that's not the cause. By the way it's still not working on a sample different from the one you provided, I can't figure out why.

Comment: I can have a look later.